# how to get field value from model

Tags: django

I have a model for registering with some fields.
All fields are models I fill in through the form like this.

```
def get_name(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_code = generate_code(8)
    subject = 'code' 
    message = user_code
    phone=request.POST['phone']
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        date_use = form.cleaned_data.get("date_visit")
        time_use = form.cleaned_data.get("time_visit")
        purpose_use = form.cleaned_data.get("purpose")
        if Registration.objects.filter(date_visit=date_use,time_visit=time_use,purpose=purpose_use).count()==0:
            Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],phone=request.POST['phone'],date_visit=request.POST['date_visit'],time_visit=request.POST['time_visit'],
                number_car=request.POST['number_car'],purpose=request.POST['purpose'],
                tso=request.POST['tso'])
            request.session["phone"] = phone
            request.session["code"] = user_code
            return HttpResponseRedirect('endreg')
else:
    form = NameForm()
return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})
```

The model also has a field

```
date_register = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'date register', auto_now_add=True)
```

how can i write date_register value in request.session["date"] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Registration.objects.create(...)` you can use `.save` method:

```
obj = Registration()
obj.fio = form.cleaned_data["fio"]
...
obj.save()
request.session["date"] = str(obj.date_register)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default django use `JSONSerializer` and it can't dump datetime objects.

The simplest solution is using `PickleSerializer` as `SESSION_SERIALIZER`, but it can cause performance issues (docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_SERIALIZER)

Another way to do it - write you custom json serializer, based on django serializer, but with default function for dumping datetime objects, or simple convert date to string format or timestamp before saving to session.